# XOR of a shell variable and a binary file

Tags: shell-script

I have a password stored in a shell variable (which was read from command line input).

I also have a keyfile stored in a file (which was created using `dd` and `/dev/urandom`).

Since I want to require both of those to decrypt my hard drive, I would like to XOR them, store it in a file and use that as key.

I would therefore like to know what the simplest way of doing that would be.

`xxd` would be a perfect fit if it allowed `-b` and `-p` at the same time but apparently, it doesn't...

---

Edit: I'll use it in https://github.com/xavierm02/combine-keys

Comment: Instead of building your own cryptosystem (almost always a bad idea), have you considered using LUKS/dmsetup support for encrypted keyfiles? That give the two-factor authentication you seem to want. E.g., see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Using_GPG_or_OpenSSL_Encrypted_Keyfiles ... or see also gpg's --symmetric option.

Comment: I don't want to mess too much with the initramfs and the configuration of those things so I installed everything with the Debian installer and used passwords and now I'm planning on using cryptsetup to replace those passwords with my new key.

Comment: And unless I'm mistaken, cryptsetup  doesn't allow to require both. So I'm planning on just giving it a keyfile that will be the XOR I'm trying to compute.

Comment: And I want to use cryptsetup and not directly dm-crypt because I'm planning on changing the password from times to times.

Comment: Why not simply concat the 2 together?

Comment: It allows you to require both, by encrypting the keyfile. I guess, if someone gives instructions of how to do that in Debian (preferably with as little initramfs hacking as possible) would that be an acceptable answer to your question? [and cryptsetup uses dm-crypt. The LUKS header is what lets you change the passphrase)]

Comment: @derobert : I want to be able to backup parts of the keyfile in several geographically distant places. If I encrypted it with the password, getting those backups would allow to bypass the password (if I backed the non-encrypted version) or would force me to update all the backups whenever I changed the password (of I backed the encrypted version) so it's not exactly what I want and while trying to do it, I found out that I'd have to mess with the initramfs to make it work so while I'm at it, I could just get the two passwords myself and give it a new password computed with those two.

Comment: @Patrick : Because the passphrase is a very specific kind of data and I don't think concatenating it with a random file (given that cryptsetup won't know it's a password since I give it as a file and will treat it as a file where each byte can be anything). I know an XOR will be at least as strong as a concatenation and I know it's feasable (worst case senario I have to write my own C executable).

Comment: @xavierm02 Ah! OK, I understand then. You're trying to implement some form of [secret sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_splitting). There is an [ssss](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/ssss) package implementing secret sharing, and also https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=617311

Comment: @derobert : I could use secret sharing to combine the keyfile and the passphrase but it seems like overkill. I will be using it for the backup of the keyfile though :)

Comment: I still don't get why concatting won't work. You lose security by doing an XOR operation, as multiple combinations can result in the same output (which is why implementing your own cryptosystem is often a bad idea). `cryptsetup` just reads a file as a key. It doesn't care what's in the file. It could be ascii, or arbitrary binary, it makes no difference.

Comment: @Patrick : I transform 4096 random bits + 8*l of far from random bits to 4096 random bits. The length is reduced a bit and maybe that reduces security a little bit but maybe it increases it a lot because I don't know how cryptsetup encrypts the masterkey but that algorithm might not like having not-so-random data in the key. Also, I'm not doing a one-time pad here. If you concatenate both, the resulting key immediately gives you both keys. If you XOR both, you get the result of the XOR, I change the password and you get it again, you would know the XOR of my two passwords...

Comment: As mentioned, `cryptsetup` doesn't care what's in the key. How is it supposed to know if the data is random? That's why it's called random, you can get anything. Why does it matter if you immediately get both keys? No matter what, if anyone gets that file, they've got a key to decrypt the system. Why would they care where that key came from?

Comment: @Patrick : I was just pointing out that I do not lose security with the XOR. Knowing that the last bytes are A-Z or 0-9 in ASCII is information. Knowing that the last bytes are that XORed with some random data is not. So using concatenation leaks some information about the result key while XOR doesn't. I don't know if this information can be used or not and it depends on how the key is used. But the XOR method can't be much weaker (because the length difference is small) but can be much stronger (because the probability distribution is uniform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell can handle bitwise ops, though, for any serious processing, it's going to be *awfully* slow, and it can't handle anything more than say 20 or so digits at a time. Still:

```
sh <<\CMD 
    printf 'printf "%%b" "\\0$((%04o^04))"'  "'a" |\
    . /dev/stdin
CMD

#OUTPUT
A
```

I've used `bc` in the past for grabbing bytes in binary, so your question set me to googling  for...

[Exclusive-or (XOR) for GNU bc](http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/bcfaq.html#bcxor)

> If you've found your way across the internet to this question, chances
>   are you're looking for bc's equivalent of C's `^` operator.
>
> Disturbing fact: no such thing exists in `bc`. In `bc`, the up-arrow
>   operator is used for integer exponentiation, that is, `2^x` returns a
>   power of 2 and not x with bit 2 flipped. If you're looking for
>   equivalents to the bitwise operators for XOR as well as AND, OR and a
>   few more exotic relatives, check out this site's logic.bc, and its
>   relatives which contain functions to perform each of these.
>
> If you're looking for a logical `XOR` to put in an if statement, like
>   logical `&&` and `||`, try using `!=` and surrounding your conditions with
>   brackets. e.g.:
>
> `c=0;if((a==1)!=(b==2)){c=3}`
>
> Will set c to 3, if a is 1 or b is 2, but
>   not if a is 1 and b is 2 at the same time
>
> (Once upon a time, this was the secret to the internals of the
>   logic.bc xor() function, but this has been superseded by a faster
>   algorithm.)

The above is from the `bc` FAQ. The `logic.bc` function alluded to above includes the `bitwise` logic you're looking for. It can be found [here](http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/index.html#logic). Its description:

> A large suite of functions to perform *bitwise* functions such as AND,
>   OR, NOT and XOR. Uses twos complement for negative numbers, unlike
>   previous versions of this file, which had no support at all. Some of
>   the functions here will use the global bitwidth variable, which itself
>   is initialised as part of this file, to emulate byte/word sizes found
>   in most computers. If this variable is set to zero, an infinite
>   bitwidth is assumed. Many functions will display a warning if there is
>   suspicion that a secondary floating point representation of a number
>   has been generated, e.g.:
>
> `1.1111... is an SFPR of`10.0000...;`
>
> These warnings can be disabled by setting the global variable `sfpr_warn` to `0`
>   (default is 1).

- Fixed word size
- Infinite word size
- Common bitwise
- Twos complement
- Bit shifting
- Gray code
- 'Multiplication'
- Floating point
- Floating point 'Multiplication'
- Gray code + Floating point

Comment: This is a description of a logical (boolean) xor operation,  not a binary (bit-by-bit) xor the OP was asking for.

Comment: @danielkullmann - very good point, thanks. I'll have the update live in a moment.

Comment: @danielkullmann - it's a little better now.

Comment: You code would be much easier to read if you used variables instead of having this expression with a printf printing a printf... Anyway, I'll accept this answer but still go with the C binary since it will be way faster.

Comment: @xavierm02 - You don't have to accept this - your answer is *way* better than mine. This was just an alternative because I thought your question was a very good one (just now remembered to upvote it though - sorry) and I had a tiny bit of knowledge that some others who happen upon it in future might be able to use. You know - for progeny or whatever. I'll fix the `printf` statement - but not with shell variables - it's slow enough as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I used a C binary.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No argument given.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *filename = argv[1];

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open given file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    int c1;
    int c2;
    do {
        c1 = fgetc(stdin);
        c2 = fgetc(file);
        if (c1 == EOF) {
            while (c2 != EOF) {
                printf("%c", c2);
                c2 = fgetc(file);
            }
            break;
        } else  if (c2 == EOF) {
            while (c1 != EOF) {
                printf("%c", c1);
                c1 = fgetc(stdin);
            }
            break;
        }
        int c = c1 ^ c2;
        printf("%c", c);
    } while (true);

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something nearly working in SH but it's way too slow

```
#!/bin/sh

small_hex_to_bin() {
    hex=$1
    hex_length=${#1}
    bin=$(echo "ibase=16;obase=2;$hex" | bc)
    bin_length=$((4*$hex_length))
    bin=$(printf %0*d $bin_length $bin)
    echo $bin
}

hex_to_bin() {
    hex=$1
    hex_length=${#hex}
    for i in $(seq 1 $hex_length); do
        hex_digit=$(expr substr $hex $i 1)
        bin_digits=$(small_hex_to_bin $hex_digit)
        echo -n $bin_digits
    done
    echo ""
}

bin_to_hex() {
    bin=$1
    hex=$(echo "ibase=2;obase=10000;$bin" | bc)
    echo $hex
}

char_to_hex() {
    char=$1
    hex_lower=$(printf %x \'$char\')
    hex=$(echo $hex_lower | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
    echo $hex
}

char_to_bin() {
    char=$1
    hex=$(char_to_hex $char)
    bin=$(small_hex_to_bin $hex)
    echo $bin
}

string_to_bin() {
    s=$1
    l=${#s}
    for i in $(seq 1 $l); do
        char=$(expr substr $s $i 1)
        bin=$(char_to_bin $char)
        echo -n $bin
    done
    echo ""
}

file_to_bin() {
    filename=$1
    hex_spaces=$(xxd -u -p $filename)
    hex=$(echo $hex_spaces | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' ')
    bin=$(hex_to_bin $hex)
    echo $bin
}

min() {
    if [ $1 -ge $2 ]; then
        echo $2
    else
        echo $1
    fi
}

bit_xor() {
    if [ $1 -eq $2 ]; then
        echo 0
    else
        echo 1
    fi
}

xor() {
    b1=$1
    b2=$2
    l1=${#b1}
    l2=${#b2}
    l=$(min $l1 $l2)
    for i in $(seq 1 $l); do
        c1=$(expr substr $b1 $i 1)
        c2=$(expr substr $b2 $i 1)
        c=$(bit_xor $c1 $c2)
        echo -n $c
    done
    next_i=$(($l + 1))
    if [ $l -ne $l1 ]; then
        for i in $(seq $next_i $l1); do
            c1=$(expr substr $b1 $i 1)
            echo -n $c1
        done
    fi
    if [ $l -ne $l2 ]; then
        for i in $(seq $next_i $l2); do
            c2=$(expr substr $b2 $i 1)
            echo -n $c2
        done
    fi
    echo ""
}

#stdin=$(cat)
#file=$(cat $1)
#hex_to_bin $1
file_to_bin $1
```

Comment: Don't use that, guy. This is how you do it in the shell: `_c2o() { od -A n -t o1 -w1 -v ; }`

Comment: And if you want to do case conversion, `dd` is the tool for you.

Comment: `for i in seq` is *bad.* You've gotta steer clear of common shell/readline constructs and work with files and streams. For instance: `eval printf "%*s" "$(seq -s' "$var" ' ${#var})"` should take a variable apart char by char in one shell op. But better than that is `dd cbs=1 conv=unblock` or `od -A n -a -w1.` Also, I have a bunch of these little functions and things if you want - with `bc` even, including a simple echo sttement for streamed binary conversion. But `C` was a better way to go if you ask me...

Comment: I did go with C. You're saying I should use stream. But since I have two inputs (for the xor part) I don't see how I could do that. (For the rest of it, I guess it'd be possible)

Comment: You would have to `select` the bits out of the stream and keep them streaming - i dont know `C` but i once did something similar to your `XOR` function. I computed all possible upper-lower case variations for an arbitrary char string by requesting all the binary representations of the numbers from 0 to string `$len` and then translating 1 to lower and 0 to upper for my string. I did this in the shell and i used a lot of `tees` to sort of `ring-buffer` the stream as i selected from the stream. The problem with the above is every `$(sub)` is a blocking op - youll never get anything done.